# How to perform Grid Search on NLP CRF model

Tags: nlp, machine-learning-model, gridsearchcv

I am trying to perform hyperparameter tuning on sklearn_crfsuite.CRF model. When I try to execute below code, it doesn't give any exception but it probably fails to perform fit. And due to which, if I try to get best estimator from grid search, it doesn't work.

```
%%time
# define fixed parameters and parameters to search
crf = sklearn_crfsuite.CRF(
    algorithm='lbfgs',
    max_iterations=100,
    all_possible_transitions=True
)
params_space = {
    "c1": [0,0.05,0.1, 0.25,0.5,1],
    "c2": [0,0.05,0.1, 0.25,0.5,1]
}

# use the same metric for evaluation
f1_scorer = make_scorer(metrics.flat_f1_score,
                        average='weighted', labels=labels)

# search
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=crf,
                           param_grid=params_space,
                           cv=3,
                           n_jobs=-1, verbose=1,scoring=f1_scorer)

#grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)
#above code throws exception, which seems to be a open bug in latest version of scikit-learn 0.24.0 or later.
#github link for bug: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite/issues/60
try:
    grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)
except AttributeError as e:
     if "'CRF' object has no attribute 'keep_tempfiles'" not in str(e):
        raise
```

Any help would be appreciated, how can I perform hyperparameter tuning here?

I took reference using this [tutorial](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#hyperparameter-optimization), but stuck in same situation.

Answer (score 1):

The code does produce an exception indeed, but it is catched by the try-except. To avoid the exception, you could modify your local copy of the sklearn_crfsuite library and add the missing attributes (`keep_tempfiles` and `model_filename`).

1. Edit `sklearn_crfsuite/estimator.py` and add this to the `__init__()` method of the CRF class.

```
self.keep_tempfiles = keep_tempfiles
self.model_filename = model_filename
```

2. Remove the try-except from your code.

```
grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

It is running fine for me with a toy dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how could we resolve it in sci-kit version 0.24 or later but when I downgraded it to 0.23.2 version, same piece of code seems to be working fine.